# Ruby - determining method origins?

Tags: ruby

When sent a message, a Ruby object searches to see whether it has a method by that name to respond with. Its method lookup searches in the following order, and uses the first method it finds.

1. Singleton methods defined on itself (aka methods on its "eigenclass")
2. Methods defined in its class
3. Any modules mixed into its class, in reverse order of inclusion (only the earliest inclusion of a given module has any effect - if the superclass includes module A, and the subclass includes it again, it’s ignored in the subclass; if the subclass includes A then B then A, the second A is ignored) (**update**: note that this was written before `Module.prepend` existed)
4. Its parent class
5. Any methods mixed into the parent class, the parent's parent, etc.

**Or, to put it more simply, it looks on itself, then everything in `self.class.ancestors` in the order they're listed.**

This lookup path is followed at the moment the method is called; if you make an instance of a class, then reopen the class and add a method or mix one in via a module, the existing instance will gain access to that method.

If all of this fails, it looks to see if it has a `method_missing` method, or if its class does, its parent class, etc.

My question is this: **aside from examining the code by hand, or using example methods like `puts "I'm on module A!"`, can you tell where a given method came from?** Can you, for example, list an object's methods and see "this one is on the parent class, this one is on module A, this one is on the class and overrides the parent class," etc?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) returns a [`Method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html) object giving meta-data about a given method. For example:

```
> [].method(:length).inspect
=> "#<Method: Array#length>"
> [].method(:max).inspect
=> "#<Method: Array(Enumerable)#max>"
```

In Ruby 1.8.7 and later, you can use [`Method#owner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-owner) to determine the class or module that defined the method.

To get a list of all the methods with the name of the class or module where they are defined you could do something like the following:

```
obj.methods.collect {|m| "#{m} defined by #{obj.method(m).owner}"}
```

Comment: you can get the #owner method in 1.8.6 by using the backports gem.

Comment: Another bit of awesomeness: `Method` objects also have a `source_location` method. "Now where is that pesky monkey patch?..." :)

Comment: Can't believe I had no idea on that. So useful! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Get the appropriate Method (or UnboundMethod) object and ask for its `owner`. So you could do `method(:puts).owner` and get `Kernel`.

Comment: Your answer together with the accepted answer are pure light in the darkness, man. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To find which instance methods are defined on `A` (but not on superclasses):

```
A.instance_methods(false)
```

To find which instance methods are defined on `A` AND its superclasses:

```
A.instance_methods
```

To find which class (or module) a given method is defined on:

```
method(:my_method).owner
```

To find which object is the receiver for a given method:

```
method(:my_method).receiver
```

Comment: To get specific types of methods: someobject.private_methods, someobject.public_methods, someobject.protected_methods, someobject.singleton_methods, SomeClass.instance_methods, SomeClass.private_instance_methods, SomeClass.protected_instance_methods, SomeClass.public_instance_methods (which is the same as just .instance_methods).

Comment: This does not appear to be the case (see [gist](https://gist.github.com/dmoles/dbcbfd49bb05969c139120e1e4d0e645)). Or if it is, it's true in some very non-obvious way.

Comment: @DavidMoles you're right, it should have been `instance_methods` not `methods`, i updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object#method`. For example,

```
[1, 2, 3].method(:each_cons) # => #<Method: Array(Enumerable)#each_cons>
```

tells that the each_cons method of an Array comes from the Enumerable module.