# How to call namespace method on namespaced class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, class, module

I'm writing some class inside module:

```
module A
end

module A::B
  def foo
    print "foo"
  end
end

class A::B::C
end

A::B::C.new.foo # => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<A::B::C...>
```

How can I define method in module B to call in the class C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as if you write:

```
module A::B
  def foo
    print "foo"
  end

  class C
  end
  print 'C.instance_methods : '; p C.instance_methods(false)
  #=> C.instance_methods : []
end
```

`C` does not automatically inherits `foo`. There are only two ways to inherit instance methods:

1. `class C < super_class` where `super_class` is an expression returning a class
2. Including a module:

   ```
   class C
     include <some module>
   ```

For an explanation of the superclass chain, see [How does Inheritance work in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153667/how-does-inheritance-work-in-ruby/14155007#14155007) and [Ruby: Module, Mixins and Blocks confusing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088513/ruby-module-mixins-and-blocks-confusing/14090170#14090170)

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces in Ruby don’t work the way you seem to think.

1. There is no such thing as a “namespace method”. `A::B#foo` is an *instance method* on the *module* `A::B`—which is a module named `B` in the namespace of `A`.
2. Namespaces modules/classes have *no* special relationship of inheritance between them. They are *purely organizational in nature*, except when defined the long way (e.g. `module A; module B; end; end`) when they can affect lexical scope.

If you want to get methods of `A::B` in `A::B::C`, you must `include A::B` in `A::B::C`, just like you would anywhere else. You have to do this because, as said above, there's nothing special about a namespaced module/class, it is treated the same as any other.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A::B::C
  include A::B
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But is has solution without using include A::B in A::B::C?

Comment: I don't think there are other ways. Do you have a reason to avoid using `include`?