# Ruby module prepend vs derivation

Tags: ruby

What are the differences between:

```
module Mod   
   def here
     puts 'child'
   end    
end

class A
  prepend Mod
  def here
    puts 'parent'
  end
end
```

and

```
class A
   def here
     puts 'parent'
   end
end

class B < A
  def here
    puts 'child'
  end
end
```

Or another way to put it: is derivating a class the same as prepending a module of the child's code?

Comment: `def do` is not a valid syntax.. You should give it a name.. `do` is a keyword, you can't give it a method name..

Comment: @ArupRakshit `do` is a valid method name.

Comment: @sawa I don't know... It is not indenting.. Why should one try to give a method name as `do`.. Anyway. Its other's code. I wouldn't give it a name like `do` as, `do` comes into the *block* syntax.

Comment: I changed the method name to `here` to clarify what the question is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not. `B` can only inherit from one class, but `Mod` can be prepended to many classes. If you were to call `super` inside `B#here`, it would always refer to `A#here`, but inside of `Mod#here`, it will refer to the `#here` instance method of whatever class `Mod` was prepended to:

```
module Mod   
  def here
    super + ' Mod'
  end    
end

class A
  prepend Mod
  def here
    'A'
  end
end

class B
  prepend Mod
  def here
    'B'
  end
end

A.new.here
# => 'A Mod'

B.new.here
# => 'B Mod'
```

and

```
class A
  def here
    'A'
  end
end

class B
  def here
    'B'
  end
end

class C < A
  def here
    super + ' C'
  end
end

C.new.here
# => 'A C'

class C < B
  def here
    super + ' C'
  end
end
# TypeError: superclass mismatch for class C
```

Comment: Thats because you define C class twice. Your second example uses no prepend module. :)

Comment: @muichkine: Yes, exactly. You asked about the difference between prepending a mixin and inheriting a class, and that's one of the differences: you can prepend multiple mixins, but only inherit one class.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's totally different.

One can prepend as many modules as he wants.

```
module A
  def foo; "A" end
end

module B
  def foo; "B" end
end

class C
  prepend A, B   # Prepending is done by this line

  def foo; "C" end
end
### take a look at it!
C.ancestors # => [A, B, C, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
C.new.foo # => "A"
```

Ruby implements `prepend` and inheritance using different ways.
`prepend` is internally achieved by *including modules*, which causes the surprising `ancestors`.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383878/couldnt-understand-the-moduleprepend-features-and-moduleappend-features-i) is another question about `prepend` which may be helpful.