# Delay Module#included callback?

Tags: ruby

Is it there a way to define a module callback similar to [Module#included](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included), but to be called **after** the receiver's definition is over ?

For example, in order to be able to access receiver's methods defined after the inclusion :

```
module A
  def self.included(base)

    if base.respond_to? :foo
      puts ":foo is defined in #{base}"
    else
      puts ":foo is not defined in #{base}"
    end

  end
end

class B
  include A

  def self.foo ; end
end

# :foo is not defined in B
```

It is possible to include the module at the end of the receiver's definition, but it feels less idiomatic :

```
class C
  def self.foo ; end

  include A
end
# :foo is defined in C
```

Comment: The main difference (the only one?) is that if the class mixes in a method from the module that is also in the class, the module's method will overwrite class `C`'s method and be overwritten by class `B`'s method.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to circumvent this behavior? Like, an `after_defined` hook called by the B when it reaches the end of the class definition.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a cleaner way than writing the include at the end. Do you need access to the class's definitions in the `included` hook, or are you just wanting the module methods to take priority over the class's methods? If it's the latter, you could try `prepend`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15384720/4280232

Comment: I don't know if it would buy you anything, but you could write `class B; end; B.include A`.